# Jenkins template - credentials

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to create a Jenkins Job template for my Workflow. I want to allow user to specify credentials from my list of global credentials
[image]

In my template parameter config, I add a an attribute of type Select credentials, thinking that should present a dropdown with the options from my global credentials, with the value being the ID such as bae24b40-4365-4a60-abc9-23dfc751b31b

But all I see is an empty list
[image]

Am I misinterpreting what this attribute type should do? If not, why am I not seeing the list of credentials to select?

Answer (score 0):

You are not misinterpreting the feature; you just seem to have hit some kind of bug blocking the list from being displayed. You should be able to select credentials in the template instance, and use `attributeName.getId()` from the script to access the ID. Open a support ticket with a support bundle, your template `config.xml`, etc. for diagnosis.